# jhipster side by side generator (once)

Tags: jhipster, yeoman-generator

I like the idea of the side-by-side development in JHipster to support easy upgrading, etc as demonstrated in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg5CYoBdpVo

So instead of manually creating the BandExtendedResource and the BandExtendedRepository, etc, is there already, or could there be either:

- a JDL option to indicate side-by-side is going to be used
- or a yeoman generator for these files?

I understand this could be a bit circular, in that, the point of the extended classes is that we don't overwrite them, but these could/would be excluded (one way or another) from subsequent generator runs.

Comment: +1 for your post.  i don't think there is  a  jdl option. It will be very nice to have such mecanism. I hope that some one in jhipster community  will work on this.

Comment: It looks like this may make it into jhipster 7: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10958#issuecomment-566108526